# Intelij: Keyboard Shortcut for hover over pop up?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut to activate hover over pop up?

Use case: especially needed when there is an squiggly error on some piece of code and I would like to see what the error hint is, without having to reach for the mouse to move around the function.

Answer (score 4):

Default on Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

Default on Mac: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

Comment: Does not seem to work, is this OS wide setting?

Comment: Go to file > settings > keymap, then search "Error Description". That's the setting.

In the keymap window, it's under Main Menu > View > Error Description. 

Reading your question again, I may have misunderstood. Your cursor does need to be on the part that is underlined. I'm not sure if it's possible to activate that window regardless of cursor location with out-of-the-box features.

Comment: Thank you 'Error Description' is exactly what I was looking for. Yea the cursor gets moved by 'Next Highlighted error' thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Go to `File > Settings > Keymap > Other > Hover info` and assign a keyboard shortcut to it.